# The non-linear extra sum of squares? What is this?

Tags: r, regression, nonlinear-regression, nls

I encountered in the article I read the term `the non-linear extra sum of square` with the reference to `Bates and Watts 1988`. I do not have an access to the book and even if I had it I would not be able to understand it. The concept has been used to compare two non-liner models fitted to different parts of the same data set. Can it be something like this (code in R):

```
trees <- structure(list(Girth = c(8.3, 8.6, 8.8, 10.5, 10.7, 10.8, 11, 
11, 11.1, 11.2, 11.3, 11.4, 11.4, 11.7, 12, 12.9, 12.9, 13.3, 
13.7, 13.8, 14, 14.2, 14.5, 16, 16.3, 17.3, 17.5, 17.9, 18, 18, 
20.6), Height = c(70, 65, 63, 72, 81, 83, 66, 75, 80, 75, 79, 
76, 76, 69, 75, 74, 85, 86, 71, 64, 78, 80, 74, 72, 77, 81, 82, 
80, 80, 80, 87), Volume = c(10.3, 10.3, 10.2, 16.4, 18.8, 19.7, 
15.6, 18.2, 22.6, 19.9, 24.2, 21, 21.4, 21.3, 19.1, 22.2, 33.8, 
27.4, 25.7, 24.9, 34.5, 31.7, 36.3, 38.3, 42.6, 55.4, 55.7, 58.3, 
51.5, 51, 77)), .Names = c("Girth", "Height", "Volume"), row.names = c(NA, 
-31L), class = "data.frame")

mod1  <- nls(Volume ~ Height^b, start = c(b = 1.1), data = trees)
mod2  <- nls(Volume ~ Height^b, start = c(b = 1.1), data = trees[1:20,])

anova(mod1, mod2)

   Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: Volume ~ Height^b
Model 2: Volume ~ Height^b
  Res.Df Res.Sum Sq Df Sum Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
1     30     7035.5                                
2     19      510.2 11 6525.3   22.09 1.619e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

which means that the `mod1`is better than `mod2`???? or is this something else?

Answer (score 1):

This is not be a very comprehensive answer but is a bit too long for a comment.

Based on details given in [this paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00883904/document), the non-linear sum of squares is an $F$-distributed statistic, defined as

$$
F = \frac{\text{SSE}_R - \text{SSE}_F}{df_R - df_F} + \frac{\text{SSE}_F}{df_F}
$$

where

- $\text{SSE}_R$ and $\text{SSE}_F$ are the error sum of squares of the reduced and full model, respectively, and
- $df_R$ and $df_F$ are the degrees of freedom of the reduced and full model, respectively.

Comment: do you know what do they mean by "the same set of parameters" and "different set of parameters"

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to. In the expression for $F$, the reduced model refers to a model with a different (smaller) set of parameters that those from the full model. Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but a rather a comment with graphs. As graphs cannot be put into comments, I placed them here.

Consider working with 3D scatterplots and 3D surface plots of this data set. The below 3D scatterplot of Volume, Height and Girth implies that the data lies on a 3D surface, and indeed here is a plot of the fitted surface equation "Volume = a * Girth^b * Height^c" with parameters a =  1.4488265660520172E-03, b =  1.9969214716314732E+00, and c =  1.0876465342705759E+00 giving R-squared = 0.9778 and and RMSE = 2.408. Interestingly parameter b is almost 2.0 and parameter c is almost 1,0, so the true natural equation, based on this data, is likely to be "Volume = a * Girth^2 * Height".

[image: scatter]

[image: surface]

[image: contour]

Comment: how do you create the third figure?

Comment: To answer your question, I used my online open source Python  surface fitting web site zunzun.com to perform the equation search and to model the data, and it automatically created all of the plots I posted including the contour plot. Note that on a contour plot, when the lines are close together the surface is steeper, showing areas of the surface where the fitting model is changing more rapidly..

Comment: @Legionista If you want to make it yourself locally, look at [`matplotlib.pyplot.contour`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html). These [examples](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contour_demo.html) might also help.